# How to hide/un-hide a label in a CustomCell when the cell goes off the screen after scrolling - Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell, dynamic-tables

I have a `Dynamic Table` with several `Custom Cells` containing a `Label` and a `UITextField`. However, when I scroll to the bottom of the screen and tap on the `Continue` button I am having issues accessing the `Label` I want to hide/un-hide from the `Custom Cell` which has been scrolled off the screen. In other words, I get the error

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.**

when I try to get the the `Cell` using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because the `cell` is off the screen once I have scrolled down to the bottom of the screen to tap the `Continue` button.

***Table View Controller:***

```
class RNSContactInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            //street address cell
            let streetAddressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("streetAddressCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StreetAddressCell
            setStreetAddressTextFieldValue(streetAddressCell)
            return streetAddressCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            //apt or suite cell
            let aptOrSuiteCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("aptOrSuiteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AptOrSuiteCell
            setAptOrSuiteTextFieldValue(aptOrSuiteCell)
            return aptOrSuiteCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            //city cell
            let cityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CityCell
            setCityTextFieldValue(cityCell)
            return cityCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            //state cell
            let stateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StateCell
            setStateTextFieldValue(stateCell)
            return stateCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            //zip code cell
            let zipcodeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("zipcodeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ZipCodeCell
            setZipcodeTextFieldValue(zipcodeCell)
            return zipcodeCell
        } else {
            //default cell
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            return cell
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Button Tapped Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func reviewServiceOrderButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        //Dismiss keyboard when button is tapped
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        //Set user fields
        //<==========THE LINE BELOW IS CRASHING============>
        let streetAddressCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)) as! StreetAddressCell
        //<================================================>

        //<======THIS IS WHERE I TRY TO UN-HIDE THE LABEL======>
        if (self.streetAddress.isEmpty) {
            //Show asterisk for required field
            streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressAsteriskLabel(false)
        }
        //<=================================================>
    }

    //Setting text fields and text views for each appropriate cell
    func setStreetAddressTextFieldValue(streetAddressCell: StreetAddressCell) {
        streetAddressCell.streetAddressTextField.delegate = self
        if (self.streetAddress.isEmpty || self.streetAddress == SINGLE_WHITE_SPACE_STRING_CONSTANT) {
            streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressPlaceholderText(ADDRESS_PLACEHOLDER_STRING_CONSTANT)
        } else {
            streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressText(self.streetAddress)
        }
        streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressAsteriskLabel(true)
    }

    @IBAction func streetAddressTextFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        //Hide asterisks for required fields
        let streetAddressCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)) as! StreetAddressCell
        //streetAddressCell.streetAddressAsterisk.hidden = true
        streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressAsteriskLabel(true)
        checkMaxLength(sender, maxLength: 100)
        self.streetAddress = streetAddressCell.getStreetAddressText()
    }
}
```

***Custom Cell:***

```
class StreetAddressCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var streetAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var streetAddressAsterisk: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Getter Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    func getStreetAddressText() -> String {
        return self.streetAddressTextField.text!
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Setter Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    func setStreetAddressText(text: String) {
        self.streetAddressTextField.text = text
    }

    func setStreetAddressPlaceholderText(placeholderText: String) {
        self.streetAddressTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholderText,
                                                                                                                   attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()])
    }

    func setStreetAddressAsteriskLabel(value: Bool) {
        self.streetAddressAsterisk.hidden = value
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't misuse the view (cell) as model (data source). Create a reasonable model and get and set the values there. Then all UI elements a updated properly in `cellForRow` and your issues disappear.

Comment: @vadian, could you make a recommendation on a better model for the situation I am describing, where I want to hide/unhide a label depending on the text of the text field. Thanks

Comment: Create a custom struct / class with `street`, `apt`, `city` etc. properties and set the text fields respectively in `cellForRow`. Then *hide/unhide a label depending on the **property in the model***. Never retrieve data from the view in such a case.

Comment: I am not retrieving data from the view, I am validating the text fields' text at the time that the text fields are edited and I am then saving the text to a variable for validation at the time that the Continue button is tapped. I have updated my question to reflect this. However, what I am having trouble with is accessing the UI elements at the time the Continue button is tapped and the table has already been rendered. Should I be reloading the table to hide/unhide the labels at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is off the screen and thus `nil` as `UITableView` reuses cells. By saying:

```
let streetAddressCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)) as! StreetAddressCell
```

with `as!` you are force down casting to `StreetAddressCell` this will only succeed if `self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0))` is not `nil` and of type `StreetAddressCell`. To do this in a safer way you should say something like:

```
if let streetAddressCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)) as? StreetAddressCell, self.streetAddress.isEmpty
{
    streetAddressCell.setStreetAddressAsteriskLabel(false)
}
```

You will also need to update your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to manage this new state.